# GNU Make --output-sync doesn't work?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

this is driving me bonkers.

For parallel make builds (-j), you're supposed to be able to synchronize the console output. Here is ref:

- [GNU Make Manual: 5.4.1 Output During Parallel Execution](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel-Output.html)

I'm using GNU Make 3.82 for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu

**Un-Synchronized:**

```
make -j8 all         //not synchronized
```

yields (i'm using eclipse-cdt managedbuild here):

```
Building file: ../dome.c
Building file: ../main.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"dome.d" -MT"dome.d" -o "dome.o" "../dome.c"
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.c"
Finished building: ../dome.c
Finished building: ../main.c


Building target: empty_linux
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc  -o "empty_linux"  ./dome.o ./main.o   
Finished building target: empty_linux
```

**Synchronized Attempt**

```
make -j8 all --output-sync
```

yields (same result for -O/-Oline/etc):

```
make: unrecognized option '--output-sync
```

**Question**

what the heck am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `--output-sync` option is only available in [GNU make 4.0](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/make-w32/2013-10/msg00021.html). Also, in your case you should use:

```
--output-sync=target
```

or

```
-Otarget
```

But this won't work with version 3.82.

Comment: eeks; i feel silly. it is indeed a 4.0 feature. now if my weak-linux skills could just figure out how to upgrade it... thanks!

Comment: `wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/make-4.0.tar.bz2 && tar xjf make-4.0.tar.bz2 && cd make-4.0 && ./configure && make && sudo make install` then `/usr/local/bin/make --version`.  All done! :-)