# How can I install a newer version of make on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, makefile, homebrew

Mac OS comes with make version 3.81 and I want a newer version (`>=4.0`) for use on some projects.

How can I install a newer version, preferably using brew?

That's related to [GNU Make --output-sync doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22277483/gnu-make-output-sync-doesnt-work) as I want to use some feature output sync on parallel builds.

Comment: `homebrew/dupes/make` is the recipe you are looking for.

Comment: I did `brew install homebrew/dupes/make` but it did not enable the new make. I even logged in again and tried a `which -a make` and still only one result, the `/usr/bin/make`. Did I miss something?

Comment: Please make it an answer so I can accept it. Thank you!

Comment: btw, I tried `brew install --with-default-name homebrew/dupes/make` but while it did install it, it did not install it in the page. Which is still not able to find it but I can confirm that `gmake` is available.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating Make Version 4.1 on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175529/updating-make-version-4-1-on-mac)

Answer (score 9):

brew ships a `make` in the `homebrew/dupes` tap. `brew install homebrew/dupes/make` puts a `gmake` binary in the PATH to avoid clashes with the default make version on macOS.

The option `--with-default-names` will install as `make` and thus shadow the default version.

See `brew info homebrew/dupes/make` for more details.

```
homebrew/dupes/make: stable 4.2.1 (bottled)
Utility for directing compilation
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/
/usr/local/Cellar/make/4.2.1 (12 files, 957.3K) *
  Poured from bottle on 2016-08-11 at 20:18:41
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/blob/master/make.rb
==> Dependencies
Optional: guile ✘
==> Options
--with-default-names
        Do not prepend 'g' to the binary
--with-guile
        Build with guile support
```

Comment: I have been using homebrew (cli "brew") for over a year now and I must admit that it is much more efficient than MacPorts (cli "port") or Fink. but of course I like all the initiatives to port Linux programs to Darwin.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I made a typo here: It's `--with-default-names`. `brew install make --with-default-names` works for me. Sorry for the confusion. I deleted all my erroneous comments.

Comment: If anyone wants to get guile working with GNU make for macOS v.4.2.1, I found that the brew package fails to install guile even if you pass the `--with-guile` option.  This is because the configure script that comes with the package brew uses hard-codes the package name `guile-2.0` when you more likely have `guile-2.2` or higher.  So you must download the tar `https://ftpmirror.gnu.org/make/make-4.2.1.tar.bz2` and make it yourself, search and replacing `guile-2.0` with your actual guile package version as reported by `pkg-config --list-all`.  Sigh.

Comment: I got this error while trying to install Make using Brew. 

`Updating Homebrew...
Error: homebrew/dupes was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.`

Comment: Note: `--with-default-names` was removed from brew. See [Why was –with-default-names removed?](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/why-was-with-default-names-removed/4405/). And [Updating Make Version 4.1 on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175529/updating-make-version-4-1-on-mac) for an alternative.