# Is make installed with xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, makefile, direnv

Backstory: 
Learning to code - python web development.  I am trying to install direnv to have virtual environments.  It says it has a dependency of make and go.  https://direnv.net/

Question: 
I was looking up make and it appears it might be installed with xcode?  Is that right?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/38903785/192373

Comment: Recent macOS versions have stubs of all dev-tools in `/usr/bin`. You can either install Xcode or the Commandline Tools package. If I remember correctly, simply calling one of the commandline tools like `clang` should offer to install the commandline tools package if if no Xcode is installed.